# Why sending email is not working in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, authentication

I am sending an email using CodeIgniter Version 2.2.1. But it is giving me error. Here is my PHP code:

```
       $config = array(
            'protocol'=>'smtp',
            'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port'=>465,
            'smtp_user'=>'xxx@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass'=>'xxx'
        );

        $this->load->library('email',$config);

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com', "My Name");
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();
        return $this->email->print_debugger();
```

But when I send, it is giving me this error. I tried many ways. Why is this happening?

```
   220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp

hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [61.4.76.240]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp

from: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp

The following SMTP error was encountered: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp

to: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp

The following SMTP error was encountered: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp

data: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp

The following SMTP error was encountered: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp
The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. ci2sm13227458pbc.66 - gsmtp
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 08:45:28 +0200
From: "War" <iljimae.ic@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <iljimae.ic@gmail.com>
To: iljimae.ic@gmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?subject?=
Reply-To: "iljimae.ic@gmail.com" <iljimae.ic@gmail.com>
X-Sender: iljimae.ic@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <561f4b884c5d7@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Every find bro ? I am here for u .
```

I am using localhost by xampp. Do I need to configure something in my localhost?

Comment: Its auth failure, means user name or password are incorrect

Comment: Sorry . Posted wrong error message . Now I edited it . So please what is the issue ?

Comment: your startTLS command isnt executing , which means that TLS PORTS are either disabled , or they are not added in the firewall

Comment: So please how can I enable TLS PORTS ?

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: try this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I completely turn off the firewall . But not working

Comment: try this `'smtp_port'=> 587;`

Comment: Also if above dont work try  `'smtp_host'=>'smtp.googlemail.com',` with `port 587 and 465` alternatively or `'smtp_host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',`

Comment: Not working at all . I am using localhost and I am in Myanmar now . Why please ?

Comment: Show us what you changed, maybe there'd be a mistake you didn't notice

Comment: hey Refer to this answer this will help you ..<br>[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624376/sending-mail-using-gmail-codeigniter-wamp-localhost/49081222#49081222)

Comment: Try this answer this will help..
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624376/sending-mail-using-gmail-codeigniter-wamp-localhost/49081222#49081222)

Comment: Mate. I have got the answer since long ago. Thanks for ur help though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me. Finally I got the answer . The problem was from google. It is blocking the less secure apps . So I just navigated to this url https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps after sign in to google and turn on the access for less secure apps . You can find out more details at there .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function some_name() {

    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '*****@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '*****',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );            

    /* 
    *
    * Send email with #temp_pass as a link
    *
    */

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('****@gmail.com', "****");
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject("***********");

    $message = "<p>Your Account ************</p>";
    $this->email->message($message);
    $result = $this->email->send();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public function sendEmail(){
    //now copy and paste the below code
    $this->load->library('email');  
    $html = "Test email";
     $email_setting = array('mailtype'=>'html');
     $this->email->initialize($email_setting);
     $this->email->from('Test');
     $this->email->to('the email address');
     $this->email->subject('Title': 'New email');
     $this->email->message($html);
     $this->email->send();
}
```

Let me know if this work.
you can modify your code later on.
For more how to send email in codeigniter try this link http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-send-email-using-codeigniter/

Comment: the rest of $email_setting will be same as my $config ?

Comment: Yes you can use any one of both

Comment: try to run with my code first and check if it work you can modify your code later on

Comment: Okay I have updated my answer.Copy and paste the code in your controoler and updated your email address in $this->email->to('the email address'); and run the function. This code is working on my system

Comment: for more the link I have given you.

Comment: There was an mistake in the answer I have updated again try again

Answer (score 0):

This is a fully working email function that I'm currently using.

```
public function send_email($to, $subject, $message)
{
    // Initilize email configuration
    $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'intsmtp.abc.com.sg',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('ABCMaster');
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);

    return ($this->email->send()); // returns TRUE or FALSE
}
```

Here's how I used it:

```
$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "Learning ABCs";
$message = "ABCs are very simple. I am using them now.<br>";
$message .= "If you would like to learn more, please contact me.";

// Send email
if ( $this->send_email( $to, $subject, $message ) )
{
    // Sending email success
}
else
{
    // Sending Email has failed
}
```

Comment: If it's the same error then I suggest you follow @noobie-php suggestion's link from his comment on your question.

Comment: from function take two parameters . Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Do check you code with following snippets

```
$config = array( 
    'protocol' => 'smtp', 
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.google.com', 
    //'smtp_port' => '465', 
    'smtp_timeout' => '7', 
    'smtp_user' => 'info@gmail.com', 
    'smtp_pass' => 'password', 
    'charset' => 'utf-8', 
    'newline' => "rn", 
    'mailtype' => 'html', // or html 
    'wordwrap' => FALSE, 
    'validation' => TRUE // bool whether to validate email or not 
); 

$this->load->library('email'); 
$this->email->initialize($config); 
$this->email->set_newline("rn"); 
$this->email->from($email, 'Subject'); 
$this->email->to('nam@gmail.com,nam@gmail.com,nam@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Contact us form by: ' . $name); 
$this->email->message($message . '<br>website:' . $website); 
$this->email->send(); 

//echo $this->email->print_debugger(); `enter code here`
```

Please check your code with the above snippet. Debug your code for mail using  //`echo $this->email->print_debugger();`. If still problem persist then post here.