# sending mail using gmail , codeigniter ,wamp localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, wamp

I have problem to send email using `wamp server`.I got this error:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s10sm40910411wjp.3 - gsmtp 
hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [151.232.116.37]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. s10sm40910411wjp.3 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

And this is `codeigniter contoller`:

```
class SendEmail extends CI_Controller{
public function index(){

    $config=array();
    $config['protocol' ]   = 'smtp'                         ;
    $config['smtp_host']   = 'smtp.gmail.com'               ;
    $config['smtp_port']   = 465                            ;
    $config['smtp_user']   = 'test@gmail.com' ;
    $config['smtp_pass']   = 'pass'           ;
    $config['charset'  ]   = 'utf-8'                        ;
    $config['wordwrap' ]   = TRUE                           ;
    $config['validate']    = TRUE                           ;
    $config['_smtp_auth']  = TRUE                           ;
    $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl'                          ;

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('mytest@gmail.com', 'test');
    $this->email->to('mytest@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject("This is Another Email test  mail");
    $this->email->message("This is email is test for you mr me!the god is more than...");
    if($this->email->send()){
        echo 'You Are Luck!';
    }
    else{
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
}
```

Now I don't know that the problem is by gmail or my `wamp localhost` and this is config of wamp server `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` (I download
 sendmail.zip file and extract it into to the wamp64\sendmail).It is my `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` config

```
php.ini file:
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_path = "\ "D:\wamp64\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

And

```
sendmail.ini file:
auth_username=test@gmail.com
auth_password=test
smtp_server= smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port= 465
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have forgotten to enable IMAP (which also enables SMTP) access to your Gmail account.

Comment: I Enable gmail IMAP but get this error again @Chris

Answer (score 0):

Google may block sign-in attempts from some apps or devices that do not use modern security standards.

**Change account access for less secure apps** :
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I enable it .But no effect.`Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted` @Ahmad Faizal

Comment: @mrme is your problem solved? Am actually facing this same issue. 
I enabled the account access for less secure apps but still not working